# Distributing Axon Framework events using Amazon messaging services

Tags: amazon-sns, axon

Axon Framework supports [Distributing Events](https://docs.axonframework.org/v/3.1/part3/event-processing.html#distributing-events) which should allow to post events to the external message broken and read events from message broker.

Amazon provides two different messaging services

1. [Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS)](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)
2. [Amazon MQ](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/)

Questions:

1. What Amazon messaging service might be used (SQS, MQ or may be both) as message queue with Axon Framework?
2. What is the best practice for implementing distributed Axon message processing in Amazon EC2 cloud?

It looks like that Amazon MQ should work fine with Axon Framework as message queue because it supports AMQP. But I failed to find any references about any practical experience using MQ with Axon.

Comment: I’m interesting on this topic too. Any updates according this topic?

Answer (score 2):

Any messaging service implementation which supports, AMQP should work just fine with the Axon Framework. More specifically together with the `axon-amqp` dependency, as you might already have found out.

Without personally having any experience with Amazon SQS or MQ, I did a quick search on both, and it seems Amazon MQ is indeed the go to solution to distributed your events on Amazon EC2.

I do not have or heard any best practices for distributed your Axon Framework events over Amazon EC2 specifically, sadly enough, but I can share this.

All the Axon Framework (when adding the `axon-amqp` dependency) does, is subscribe to the `EventBus` and publish any incoming events on a queue; no further specifics.
Hence I'd say any best practices for general use of Amazon MQ should apply on your second question.